# How do you find the element via it's binding in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue2 how would one find an element if the bound property is known?
Is there a way to associate the two?

```html
<input ref="inputRef" v-model="model.name">
```

In this case it would be neat to be able to validate the model and then show an error on the input control without having to specify an identifier for each input.

It is possible to get the bound expression:

```js
// expression = "model.name"
const expression = inputRef.$vnode.data.model.expression
```

However to resolve every possible expression and map it onto the property seems like overkill.

As far as I can see it's not possible to add metadata to a variable in order to display error messages or associate the input with a property.

Is there a surefire way to map from an instance of a variable to the element on which it is bound inside a form?

Comment: wouldn't you just be able to get the value directly? - ie `model.name`

Comment: I think the way this is generally done is to simply update `model.name` or better yet some other validation text (can be initially hidden) beneath the input with an error message in response to onSubmit or onInput events.  The events should call a function, the function performs the validation, then an error message is conditionally shown  based on the validation result.